# Meaning of “comme ceux des pays voisins que sont …” in context?

Tags: grammaire

From a news broadcast-- I can't make sense of *comme ceux des pays* in this context. In fact I can't make sense of it in any context, the grammar just seems senseless to me. "As those of countries"??

> Les présidents de la Mauritanie, du Sénégal, du Togo et du Ghana, 4
>   pays qui ont œuvré pour résoudre la crise, ont déjà confirmé leur
>   présence…tous comme ceux des pays voisins que sont le Mali et le
>   Niger.

**Edit:** The more I stare at it, it's starting to make sense, but not completely. That whole ending clause....I get the meaning, I guess, but grammatically I just cannot follow it. "All from countries neighboring Mali and Niger."

Comment: It should be _tout comme_ not _tous comme_.

Comment: Well there's that, but still that leaves the rest. I mean, maybe if it was "comme ceux des pays dont les voisins sont le Mali et le Niger," that would make sense to me...

Comment: comme [l'ont fait] ceux des pays voisins que sont le Mali et le Niger.

Answer (score 4):

... comme ceux des pays ...

*Ceux* renvoie aux présidents cités dans la phrase précédente.

> ... tout comme les présidents des pays voisins que sont le Mali et le Niger

*Tout comme* : de la même façon, de la même manière, semble être l'orthographe qui aurait du être employée.

Mais *[l'article](http://www1.rfi.fr/lffr/articles/001/script_journal_francais_facile.asp)* utilise *tous*, on peut alors lire le texte ainsi (même si à l'écrit il manque une virgule après *tous* ; il faudrait remonter à la source audio pour savoir s'il a été prononcé *tou* ou *tousse*) :

> ... *tous* [les présidents concernés][**,**] comme [le sont] les présidents des pays voisins ...

---

*Complément*

*que* est employé ici comme pronom relatif désignant une personne ou une chose (le précédent directement)
Sans ce *que* le sujet du verbe *sont* est *présidents* et non *pays voisins*.

> tout comme les présidents des pays voisins *[]* sont le Mali et le Niger.

... phrase incohérente.

Comment: Wow, good research! That is indeed where it came from. But this still leaves the question of the oddly placed *que*. / Wow, bon récherche! C'est en effet la site à l'origine de cette émission. Mais la question reste, cela du mot *que* et son intention.

Answer (score 1):

I read the last phrase (omitting the « tous/tout » issue):

« … comme ceux des pays voisins que sont le Mali et le Niger. »

to mean:

« … just as [the presidents] of **neighboring countries, Mali and Niger** [have done]. »;

whereas you appear to read it to mean:

« … just as [the presidents] of **countries neighboring Mali and Niger** [have done]. »

If you are in fact reading it to mean the latter, then try reading it to mean the former to see if it makes more sense.

The « QUE sont le Mali et le Niger » construction perplexes me (and maybe you, too) because I always thought that 'QUI' takes a verb, whereas 'QUE' takes a subject, but maybe the subject/verb have been inverted here:

« ... QUE le Mali et le Niger sont (voisins des 4 autres pays cités) » to express that Mali and Niger are two AMONG SEVERAL countries that neighbor the other 4 countries mentioned, but not the only 2 (which perhaps « QUI sont le Mali et le Niger » might imply). (or maybe « que sont » is just an idiomatic usage that I don't recognize)

Anyway, I see that what I had intended to be a 'comment' is much too long to fit anywhere else than here as an 'answer,' but I’ll go ahead and post it anyway in hopes that it helps a little (at least to show that you weren't alone in finding this confusing).

Comment: Yes, “le Mail et le Niger” is the subject of “sont”, and “que” is an *attribut du sujet*. This is one of those few cases where the verb comes before the subject, it's pretty much always done in a relative clause when the verb is a single word and has no complement and the subject is more than a pronoun, and less common when the subject is a lesser proportion of the clause: “*les pays voisins que sont le Mail et le Niger*”, “*les pays que visitent les délégués*” or “*les pays que les délégués visitent*”, “*les pays que j'ai visités*”.